# How can I run a Jython script with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython

I am programming in Python(2.7), processing a bunch of data.
And I've got a software, what I have to use, and I want to start it automatically, and fill it up with data.

The problem is, that I cant open it with Python, because it has API only for Jython.

My question is, that how could I run a Jython script from a Python code(actually I am working on a standalone software)?
Is it even possible?

If it is, could you please give me a short example?
How to install Jython and how to run a file from python?

Comment: If I google 'jython', the first result is [jython.org], and there I find instructions on how to *download* and *install* jython.  To invoke your Jython script, consider the the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Thank you! And do you think, if I build my python program to a standalone version, and install it on an another computer, (where I didn't installed jython before) will it run as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use Jython to run everything.

Having `my_script.py` and `jython_script.py` edit `my_script.py` by adding `import jython_script` and adding call `jython_script.some_function()`.

```
# my_script.py
import jython_script

def my_function_using_some_function_from_jython_script():
    ...
    jython_script.some_function()
    ...
```

Then simply call:

```
jython my_script.py
```

I assume you do not use modules that work only with CPython.